# Calculating dates based on the current date

Tags: c#, datetime, date-format

Can any one help me to calculate the past six months,1 year , 2 year dates based on the current date using C#. for example, suppose my current date is `09-11-2012` i need to find out the dates `09-05-2012, 09-05-2010,09-05-2009` etc. I know its a mathematical trick, but i am looking for similar implementation with C#.

Comment: date.AddYears(-1): you could have searched for this yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the built-in date and calendaring library.

The quick way is to use the `DateTime` class, but if you want to do things correctly then you'd use the `Calendar` class, which give you more control over culture-specific information (because Monday is the first day of the week in China, but not in the France).

Anyway:

```
DateTime currentDate  = new DateTime( 2012, 11, 09 ); // assuming 9th November 2012
DateTime sixMonthsAgo = currentDate.AddMonths( -6 );
DateTime yearAgo      = currentDate.AddYears( -1 );
DateTime twoYearsAgo  = currentDate.AddYears( -2 );
```

As an aside, please don't write dates in "dd-mm-yyyy" format (neither with slashes or dashes) because it's ambiguous - this site has a large US audience and for some reason 'merkins use "mm/dd/yyyy", which makes no sense to me. The ideal format is "yyyy-MMM-dd" (where "mmm" is the three-letter month name, e.g. "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", etc), or at least in "yyyy-mm-dd" format, which is more compliant with ISO 8601).

Comment: Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/497a406b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx (you beat me to posting the same answer...)

Answer (score 1):

Use **[DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)**

```
DateTime value = new DateTime(2012, 11, 09);
DateTime nYearsAgo = value.AddYears(-n);
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use the `.AddMonths()` or `.AddYears()` methods on your DateTime object, and supply a negative value to effect a subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [DateTime Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/497a406b.aspx), more specifically the [AddMonths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx) and [AddYears](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears.aspx).